# Maximal subfield of a central simple algebra which is not Galois

Tags: division-algebras

In the book *Algebra IX: Finite Groups of Lie type and Finite Dimensional Algebra*, the authors Kostrikin-Shafarevich  mention (p. 159) that

> If $A$ is a central simple algebra over $F$ of finite dimension and if $K$ is a maximal subfield of $A$, then $K$ may not be Galois extension of $F$.

On the other hand, in a paper on Central Simple Algebras, Rowen mentiones

> Every division algebra of degree $2, 3, 4, 6$, or $12$ is a crossed product (*i.e. maximal subfields are Galois extensions; am I right?* Here degree of $D$ over $F$ is $n$ means $\dim_F(D)=n^2$.)

**Q.** What is example of a non-commutative simple (or division) algebra of finite dimension over $F$ in which a maximal subfield is not Galois extension of $F$?

(I have no idea of how difficult is this problem in the literature, and I have never seen simple algebras other than quaternions and matrix algebras over quaternions or fields.)

Comment: In anothe question you asked for a 9-dimensional division algebra, central over $\Bbb{Q}$ containing a copy of the non-Galois extension field $\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2)$. Is that not an answer to this question as well :-)

Comment: Agree with Jyrki; also note that this gives a counterexample to your claim in the second highlighted paragraph. In a crossed product, there *exists* a maximal subfield which is Galois; but that does not mean that *every* maximal subfield is Galois.

Comment: Further: while maximal subfields of a central *division* algebra over a given field $K$ may still be somewhat restricted, I claim that in the central simple $K$-algebra $M_n(K)$, you will find a copy of any (!) field extension $L\vert K$ with degree $[L:K] \le n$ (this should be a standard exercise in linear algebra); further, I am quite sure that those with dimension $n$ are maximal, although I don't see an elementary argument for that right now.

Comment: @Torsten [The double centralizer theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_centralizer_theorem) guarantees that any $L/K$ such that $[L:K]=n$ is maximal in $M_n(K)$. Granted, calling upon that result may be overkill :-).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: When I wrote the comment, I was actually keeping Grothendieck's Theorem about conjugacy of maximal tori (here, in $GL_n$) up my sleeve, hoping I would not be put on the spot to even formulate it. See, they use it for a more general question here: https://mathoverflow.net/q/251953/27465. Compared to that, the double centraliser theorem is indeed elementary, and I doubt one can get more elementary than that! -- Beginner: About the (weak but complicated) restrictions in the division algebra case I mentioned, compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/178999/96384.

Comment: @Torsten I am still hoping that there is something even simpler than the double centralizer. Like using the fact that a commuting set of diagonalizable matrices is simultaneously diagonalizable. But, to make the matrices representing the field diagonalizable I need to go to an algebraic closure and...

Comment: Adding [a link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3079067/11619) to the question I referred to in the first comment.