# Hasse invariants under extension of scalars

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, division-algebras, brauer-group

Let $K\subset L$ be finite extensions of $\Bbb{Q}$.

**Background.** Let $D$ be a finite dimensional division algebra with center $K$. Its class in the Brauer group $Br(K)$ then maps injectively into the direct sum of the Brauer groups $Br(K_v)$ with $v$ ranging over completions of $K$. Each of the groups $Br(K_v)\simeq \Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$, and these fit into the fundamental short exact sequence (see e.g. Chapter VIII of Milne's notes on CFT)
$$
0\to Br(K)\to\bigoplus_{v}Br(K_v)\to\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}.\qquad(*)
$$
Here the class $[D]\in Br(K)$ is mapped to $\bigoplus_v[D_v], D_v:=D\otimes_KK_v$, and we know that $[D_v]$ is non-trivial only finitely many $v$. The non-trivial components of the image are the Hasse invariants $inv(D_v)$ (viewed as elements of $\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$) of $D$, and by exactness of $(*)$ they sum up to an integer.

**Question.** We can also extend the scalars from $K$ to $L$ and form the
central simple $L$-algebra $D_L:=D\otimes_KL$. We have a natural commutative diagram (correct me if I'm wrong)
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
Br(K)&\longrightarrow&Br(K_v)\\
\downarrow&&\downarrow\\
Br(L)&\longrightarrow&\bigoplus_{w\mid v}Br(L_w),
\end{array}
$$
where all the mappings are more or less extensions of scalars, and $w$ ranges over the extensions of $v$.

> Is there a description of the mapping of the right column in terms of the behavior of $v$ in the extension $L/K$. In other words, if $v$ comes from a prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of $K$, and we know the inertia degree and ramification index of each prime $\mathfrak{P}$ of $L$ above $\mathfrak{p}$, is there a simple formula for the Hasse invariant $inv({D_L}_w)$ in terms of
>   $inv(D_v)$, $e(\mathfrak{P}\mid \mathfrak{p})$ and $f(\mathfrak{P}\mid\mathfrak{p})$ (obviously $w$ corresponding to $\mathfrak{P}$)?

**Example.** Consider the case of $K=\Bbb{Q}$ and $D=\Bbb{H}$, the ring of Hamiltonian quaternions with rational coefficients. Then $D$ has two non-trivial Hasse invariants, both $=1/2$. One at the infinite place (corresponding to the fact that $D\otimes\Bbb{R}$ is a division algebra) and the other at the prime $v=2$ ($2$ is a factor of the discriminant of a maximal order of $D$, or $-1$ is not in the image of the norm map $N:\Bbb{Q}_2(i)\to\Bbb{Q}_2$). If we use the extension field $L=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$ we get the division algebra of [Icosians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosian). The Icosian ring (a maximal order of $D_{\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5)}$) has unit discriminant, so the non-trivial Hasse invariant at $v=2$ became trivialized. This is probably related to some combination of facts

- $2$ is inert in $L/K$,
- $-1$ is a norm in the extension $L_2(i)/L_2$ because $L_2$ contains primitive third roots of unity $\omega$ and $\omega^2$ and
  $N^{L_2(i)}_{L_2}(\omega+i\omega^2)=\omega^2+\omega^4=-1$.

On the other hand $D_L$ has two non-trivial Hasse invariants at the two infinite places.

---

I gave the Example to help the answerers gauge my level of familiarity with the relevant basic results. I am familiar with the construction of cyclic division algebras using non-norm elements. I waded thru Chapters 1-7 of Milne's notes in our study group 12-15 years ago, and familiarized myself with some of his extras but I'm a bit rusty. Pointers to relevant literature are welcome, but as CFT can be given in many different languages I may need help in reinterpreting the results in another.

Comment: It is a disgrace that an academic grandson of Richard Brauer is not familiar with this stuff, but here I am :-/

Comment: If you enjoyed this question, you may also want to take a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/178999/11619).

Comment: For $L/K$ cyclic, this should be easy.  In general, I guess you need to understand the subfield lattice for $L_w/K_v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start from the cohomological characterization of the Brauer group of any field $K$ as $Br(K) = H^2(G_K, \bar K ^{*})$, then the extension map $Br(K) \to Br(L)$ in a field extension is just the cohomological restriction $res_{L/K}$.

Now, if $K$ is a number field, $Br(K)$ is described by the exact sequence (*) which you wrote down (NB: the "sum of components" map on the right is surjective), with $Br(\mathbf R) =\mathbf Z /2\mathbf Z$ , $Br(\mathbf C) = 0$ and for a non archimedean place $v$, $ Br(K_v) \cong \mathbf Q / \mathbf Z$ by the local Hasse invariant. Then, for a place $w$ of  $L$ above a place $v$ of $K$, the local restriction map $ Br(K_v) \to Br(L_w)$ in the right column of your commutative diagram is just the multiplication by the degree of $L_w /K_v$ (this can be viewed as a result of local CFT in cohomological terms, see e.g. Serre's "Local Fields", chapter 13) .

Comment: I don't have Serre's book on hand, but is what you say about the local restriction map true even when $L_w/K_v$ is nonabelian?

Comment: It's a general property (the proof reduces the big $H^2$ of the absolute Galois group to that of the maximal unramified extension of the local field). Another reference than Serre is Kato-Kurokawa-Sato, "Number Theory 2, Introduction to CFT", Translations of Math. Monographs, vol. 40.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain this! I was expecting eventual ramification of $L_w/K_v$ to also play a role. Basically because I thought I had convinced myself that (locally) extending the rational quaternions by $\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt2)$ didn't split it. I will recheck my calculations, as this was anything but crystal clear :-)