# I understand what a division ring is, but cannot find any examples. Can anyone give me one?

Tags: ring-theory, algorithms

From Wolfram Alpha I have that the definition of a division ring is;

"a ring in which every nonzero element has a multiplicative inverse, but multiplication is not necessarily commutative". Can someone give me an example of a division ring  where multiplication is commutative and one where it is not commutative?

Comment: The quaternions are the principal example.

Answer (score 3):

A division ring ring with commutative multiplication is the same thing as a field, so examples include $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbb{C}$. (In fact, division rings were once called fields, and fields, commutative division rings; division rings are sometimes called *skew fields*.)

The standard example of a division ring is the quaternions $\mathbb{H}$. A countable example is the set of quaternions with rational coefficients. By Wedderburn's (Little) Theorem, any finite division ring is necessarily commutative.

**Edit** Wikipedia has [another example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_ring#Examples) built using formal Laurent series and complex conjugation, and Jyrki Lahtonen gave a more exotic example here: [An example of a division ring $D$ that is **not** isomorphic to its opposite ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45085/an-example-of-a-division-ring-d-that-is-not-isomorphic-to-its-opposite-rin?rq=1) .