# Example of the semisimple ring $R$ but $R^{{\rm op}}$ is not.

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Is there any example of this kind of rings? i don't have any imagine of this rings, if they are exist!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Wedderburn-Artin theorem, a semisimple ring is a product of full matrix rings over division rings. Conversely, a product of simple artinian rings (like full matrix rings over division rings) is semisimple. This is left-right symmetric.

Comment: @ egreg: thanks for your complete answer.

Comment: Just a nitpick, but "left-right symmetric" is the phrase you're looking for. Great answer, though.

Comment: @rschwieb The property of being semisimple is left-right invariant.

Comment: @egreg I know what you mean, but you will find that it is hard to find that phrase the way you are using it, but it is very easy to find the one I'm using. Although I guess one can make an argument for "invariant," it is still not as natural or standard of a choice as "symmetric"

Answer (score 0):

No. Every semisimple ring is isomorphic to its opposite ring, and this fact is a corollary of Artin-Wedderburn theorem. So if $R$ is semisimple, then $R^{op}$ is semisimple.

Comment: Isomorphic? Perhaps you're thinking to commutative rings.

Comment: No. If you have a matrix ring $R=M(n \times n, D)$, then transposition of matrices is an isomorphism between $R$ and $R^{op}$. The same holds for products of such rings, and all semisimple rings are of this form.

Comment: @Crostul Even if $K$ is a division ring not a field? In particular, does a division ring necessarily have an involution?

Comment: Mh. I never checked it: does $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$ fail in the non commutative case?

Comment: @Crostul Try it. `;-)` It's easy: use $n=1$.

Comment: @Crostul Sorry, I have to downvote this. The idea is good, of course, but the statement that a semisimple ring is isomorphic to its opposite ring is false.

Comment: @Crostul I had to downvote for the same reason. There are even [division rings which aren't isomorphic to their opposite rings.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/45085/29335). It's also an important lesson that transposition in $M_n(R)$ isn't an anti-homomorphism when $R$ is not commutative.