# Every module over a division ring is free?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am currently trying to answer the following true/false question:

> True or False:  Every module over a division ring $R$ is free.

I know the result would be true if $R$ is a field (ie a commutative division ring), but I'm unsure if the statement is necessarily true for non-commutative division rings.  I'm guessing the best way to try and find a counterexample is to let $R = \mathbb{H}$ (real quaternions), but I don't really have any ideas / experience with examples of $\mathbb{H}$-modules.

So is this statement actually true, or is their a example (preferably of a $\mathbb{H}$-module) which is not free?

Many thanks!

Comment: A big discussion of vector spaces over division rings is here:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45056/linear-algebra-over-a-division-ring-vs-over-a-field

Comment: Did not see that discussion; thanks!

Comment: Have you tried going through your favorite proof that every vector space has a basis, and checking whether it will work for arbitrary division rings? If it does, then you've answered your question. If it doesn't, then pinpointing the step that fails will give you a crisper target for constructing a counterexample.

Answer (score 7):

Not only it holds true, but it is a *characterisation of division rings*(unfortunately you need Zorn's Lemma).