# Let $D$ be a division ring. Show that if every $a \in D$ is algebraic over the prime subfield of $D$ then $D$ is commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, division-algebras, division-ring

> Let $D$ be a division ring. Show that if every $a \in D$ is algebraic over the prime subfield of $D$ then $D$ is commutative ($D=Z(D)$).

Comment: This conclusion would imply that any finite dimensional division algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$ is commutative, which is absurd.

Comment: Hint :Jacobson says that for every $a\in R$ there exists an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a^{n}=a$, then $R$ is commutative.

Comment: Chiming in with others. This is extremely and absurdly wrong. For example all the elements of the non-commutative division rings listed in the answers [in this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/45056/11619) are algebraic over the prime subfield.

Answer (score 2):

A counterexample is $\mathbb Q(i,j,k)$ inside the quaternions. (Use that every pure quaternion has a real square.)