# Normal forms for matrices over division rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, modules

Suppose that $D$ is a division ring, $V$ is a finite-dimensional right vector space over $D$, and $f: V \to V$ is a $D$-linear map. Are there known canonical forms for $f$, in the spirit of the Jordan normal form or rational canonical form, but in the case where $D$ is noncommutative? I'm particularly interested in the case of $D = \mathbb{H}$ the quaternions, but would be very happy to see more general results too.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/45056/29335)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out

> Cohn, P. (1995). Skew Fields: Theory of General Division Rings (Encyclopedia of Mathematics and its Applications). Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. doi:10.1017/CBO9781139087193

In particular they have chapters entitled things like

- Normal forms for matrix blocks over firs
- Normal forms for matrices over a tensor ring
- Normal forms for a single matrix over a skew field

Comment: The reference given is incorrect: It is to the book review by Strambach, but the actual book is by P.M. Cohn alone and can be found at https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139087193

Comment: @BjornPoonen fixed, and thanks!